# Position of particlesystem isn't attached to object

Tags: unity-game-engine

I added a particle system to my unity project. But I can't make it attach to a certain game object or tag. How can I make a `Particle System` sit on the center of a cube, while it's getting played once if the player triggers with this cube?

Code used for the trigger to work:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Collision_Player_grower : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Player_grower;
    public ParticleSystem CollisionGrower;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        times_player_grower = 0;
        CollisionGrower.transform.position = Player_grower.transform.position;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            print("we hit an playergrower");
            CollisionGrower.Play();
            Destroy(Player_grower);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: It does work if I manually place the particle system in the heart of the cube, but I assume this can be done in an easier way.

Comment: Why is the particle system not simply a child of the player?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you want the position of the particle system to be in the center of another object.

**1)**

You could do that simply by attaching a particle system game object as a child of the cube you were talking about.

**2)**

You could do this with code instead. In case you want the particle system to do something extra, you could just adjust the code.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Collision_Player_grower : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject ParticleSystemObject;
    public GameObject Cube;

   
    public GameObject Player_grower;
    public ParticleSystem CollisionGrower;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        times_player_grower = 0;
        CollisionGrower.transform.position = Player_grower.transform.position;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        ParticleSystemObject.transform.position = Cube.transform.position;
    }
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            print("we hit an playergrower");
            CollisionGrower.Play();
            Destroy(Player_grower);
        }
    }
}
```

I don’t fully understand what the rest of the variables are for, and what they are, so I may have done some un-needed things.

First, I added two GameObject variables. One of them is the cube object you want the particle system to go to, and the other is the particle system **as a game object**. I set the position of the particle system to the position of the cube.

**Important:** if you have this script attached to the cube, remove the `Cube` variable.

Instead of using

```
... = Cube.transform.position;
```

Use

```
... = transform.position;
```